# ngbTypeahead throws exceptions

Tags: angular5, ng-bootstrap

When I try and use the ng-bootstrap (2.0.0) typeahead component I'm getting failures from inside the library itself.  I'm using this version as I can't just upgrade to Angular 6.  This is the error I'm getting.

> ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at new NgbTypeahead (typeahead.js:54)
>       at createClass (core.js:10382)
>       ...
>       at Object.debugCreateEmbeddedView [as createEmbeddedView] (core.js:12294)

I set the HTML like so:

```
<ng-template #listSelectionFormatter let-r="result">
    <span (click)="onWorkerSelected(r)">{{r.wwid}} - {{r.fullName}}</span>
</ng-template>

<div class="form-group">
    <label *ngIf="labelText" class="col-form-label" for="wwid">{{ labelText }}</label>
    <input id="wwid" name="wwid" type="text"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Search by WWID, IDSID, Name or Email"
           [ngModel]="ngModel"
           [ngbTypeahead]="search"
           [inputFormatter]="selectedResultsFormatter"
           [resultTemplate]="listSelectionFormatter"
          />
    <span *ngIf="searching">searching&hellip;</span>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">Lookup failed.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused since ng-bootstrap >= 2.0.0 _requires_ Angular >= 6.0.0. So if you can't upgrade to Angular 6 you should stick with 1.1.2 version of ng-bootstrap that still supports Angular 5.

Comment: Through the 2.1.0 release the README still refers to Angular 5, not 6, which is why I was confused.  I've got things working now by going down to the 1.1.2 version